# How to do syntax analysis of a c code in c programming language?

Tags: compiler-construction

The lexical analysis of the c code is done and the tokens are obtained. How to do the syntax analysis of the same code in c language?

Answer (score 0):

Try these tutorial links:

http://www.pling.org.uk/cs/lsa.html

http://www.c4learn.com/c-programming/syntax-analysis/

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/compiler_design/compiler_design_syntax_analysis.htm

i hope it will help you!